# (Java - Matlab) Why is my system filling my disk?

Tags: java, matlab, disk, diskspace

I have developed a System consisting of a Java and Matlab application. The Java application instantiates and uses 8 Matlab sessions with the help of Matlabcontrol.

My problem is that while the program is running it takes more and more disk space, up to 15GB. After the program has finished, the disk space is released.

The Java program does not write to disk. Only the command line is redirected to a .txt file, but this is only 50 KB. My Matlab scripts write and read MAT files. There are a lot of MAT files but they only make up around 15MB. So there can't be a resource leak. My Matlab scripts also do a lot of plotting. I'm storing the plots with the help of [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) and [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz) to .png and tikz file, respectively. The plots are hidden and closed after exported. The plots make up less than 10MB in size.

I have Windows 10 64-bit and a total of 12GB of memory. Around 80-90% of memory are used while running.

Does somebody have an idea where the problem of taking my disk space can come from? Is perhaps the memory swapping to disk? But the memory is not fully used... I have also looked into the temp dir C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ and there is no increase in size.

Does a tool exist which can show me where the disk is filled?

Comment: spacesniffer can help you out. http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/

Comment: It looks like matlab/JAVA is running out of memory space and using disk storage as a temp storage. Matlab will automatically allocate what it sees as "sufficient" memory space (based on what is available), but if your intermediate steps requires the storage of massive amount of parameters, it will use disk space instead.